# python3 zeep url gives 401 client error: unauthorized for url

Tags: python, python-3.x, soap, http-status-code-401, zeep

my command: `python3 -mzeep https://pearson:m0bApP5@cms.powerschool.com/pearson-rest/services/PublicPortalServiceJSON?wsdl`

I get an error:
`requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://pearson:m0bApP5@cms.powerschool.com/pearson-rest/services/PublicPortalServiceJSON?wsdl`

going to `https://cms.powerschool.com/pearson-rest/services/PublicPortalServiceJSON?wsdl` and authenticating manually with pearson and m0bApP5 works, but why doesn't this?

I also tried using this code, but it didn't work either.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from zeep import Client
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth  # or HTTPDigestAuth, or OAuth1, etc.
from requests import Session
from zeep.transports import Transport
session = Session()
session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth("pearson","m0bApP5")
url = "https://cms.powerschool.com/pearson-rest/services/PublicPortalServiceJSON?wsdl"
stransport = Transport(session=session)
client = Client(url,transport=stransport)
client.wsdl.dump()
```

Comment: You should not be posting auth credentials on a public website.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using HTTPDigestAuth like this:

```
session = requests.session()
session.auth = requests.auth.HTTPDigestAuth(api_username, api_password)
self.url = base_url + "pearson-rest/services/PublicPortalServiceJSON"
try:
    self.client = zeep.Client(
        wsdl=self.url + "?wsdl",
        transport=zeep.transports.Transport(session=session),
    )
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        raise APIException(f"Could not connect to {base_url}.")
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
        raise APIException(
            f"Incorrect api credentials ({api_username}, {api_password})."
        )
```